# Expression.Condition: Argument types do not match

Tags: c#, expression-trees, ternary-operator

I am trying to use an expression to create this:

```
bool.Parse("true") ? default(int?) : 1
```

BTW, I'm using `bool.Parse("true")` just to keep VS from complaining about unreachable code paths, so just assume it uses a constant `true`.  When I write my expression like this...

```
Expression.Condition(Expression.Constant(true), Expression.Default(typeof(int?)),
    Expression.Constant(1))
```

...I get the error `Argument types do not match`.  I am pretty certain that I'm aware of what's happening, so I changed my expression to do this:

```
Expression.Condition(Expression.Constant(true), Expression.Default(typeof(int?)),
    Expression.New(typeof(int?).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) }), Expression.Constant(1)));
```

It works, but I can't say I like writing an expression that's the equivalent of this:

```
bool.Parse("true") ? default(int?) : new int?(1)
```

Is there a way to get this ternary expression to work without creating a new instance of `int?`?  Perhaps it's okay to do this because c# is implicitly creating a new instance in my concrete example anyway?

**Edit**

I should note that I am only using `Expression.Constant()` to emulate a return value from a `MethodCallExpression` in order to simplify my code example.  Therefore, anything suggesting the use of constant values as a solution will not work in this case.

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem with `new int?(1)`. What exactly do you not like about it?

Comment: @svick I don't want to create a new instance of something when I can just reuse an existing instance.  I like dasblinkenlight's answer which suggests casting to `int?`.

Comment: What instance? `int?` is not a reference type and C# `new` is not C++ `new`. `new int?(1)` does the same thing as `(int?)1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a cast instead of creating an instance with `new`, i.e.

```
bool.Parse("true") ? default(int?) : (int?)(1)
```

like this:

```
Expression.Condition(
    Expression.Constant(true)
,   Expression.Default(typeof(int?))
,   Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(1), typeof(int?))
)
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/yWKqLG)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but I was hoping to avoid a cast in what I am working on.  However, maybe it's not an issue since there's probably an implicit `int-to-int?` cast going on anyway when I assign the ternary expression value to my `int?` variable.  Can you confirm if that's the case?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Unfortunately, you need a cast or an explicit type. Unlike C# compiler, which is smart to insert casts implicitly for you, LINQ expressions require you to be specific about expression types on both sides, even when you explicitly specify the overall type of the expression (see arg #4 in the demo). When you assign an expression returning an `int` to `int?`, the compiler inserts an implicit cast for you; LINQ requires you to make a `Convert` expression.

Comment: Because `(int?)(1)` is a compile-time cast, a closer analogy would be to type the constant, rather than use `Convert`.

Comment: @JonHanna Right, that's pretty much what the other answer suggests.

Comment: Yep, why I upvoted that one, though also added an answer that typed the conditional, since that's the closest logical equivalent to the first piece of code in the question (though in I think that gets compiled as a compile-time cast too).

Answer (score 1):

when you write `bool.Parse("true") ? default(int?) : 1` it actually gets compiled to something more similar to:

```
bool.Parse("true") ? default(int?) : new int?(1)
```

So why not just use a constant `int?` with a value of `1`, like so:

```
Expression.Condition(Expression.Constant(true), 
    Expression.Default(typeof(int?)), 
    Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int?)))
```

This overload of `Expression.Constant` must be used as passing an `int?` as an `object` will either box the underlying `int` or pass `null`, you must explicitly say it is an `int?` constant.

Answer (score 1):

Type the constant expression with:

```
Expression.Condition(Expression.Constant(true), 
  Expression.Default(typeof(int?)), 
  Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int?)))
```

Or type the conditional expression with:

```
Expression.Condition(Expression.Constant(true), 
  Expression.Default(typeof(int?)), 
  Expression.Constant(1),
  typeof(int?))
```

The first changes how the constant works (in both cases the value is stored as a boxed `int`, just as it would be for an `int` constant, and the unboxing, if needed, is to `int?`.

The second makes the condition itself store the type both operands must be cast to.

Note that there may not be any actual casting, especially with the first two, e.g. if you compile you are likely to compile to a form which acts on `int?` directly, so while the expression object would require a cast to act upon, the compiled code it produces does not.

Note also that some providers can't handle typed conditions, making the last option unavailable. E.g. `EnumerableQuery` can't deal with them (see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3607).